# TypeError: BrawlStarsAPI is not a constructor

Tags: javascript

I discovered this npm module that communicates with the Brawl Stars API, and I tried to implement it in my code, but it doesn't work, so I thought to try the code from the documentation, but it doesn't work either.

I tried this code from the documentation (obviously I replaced my API key with some text), but I still couldn't manage to get it to work.

```js
const BrawlStarsAPI = require("brawlstars-api-nodejs");

const client = new BrawlStarsAPI(token);

async function main() {
    const player = await client.player("#2JU9PRVUV");
    console.log(player.name);
}

main();
```

The error is:

> TypeError: BrawlStarsAPI is not a constructor

Comment: Have you tried any debugging? A console log of `BrawlStarsAPI` before using it _might_ be useful - until you try you don't know...

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It's a bit late now - I downloaded the package and followed up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debugging**

`console.log(BrawlStarsAPI)` after the `require` produces the following output:

```
{
  BattleLog: [class BattleLog extends BattleLog],
  Club: [class Club extends Club],
  ClubRanking: [class ClubRanking extends ClubRanking],
  Player: [class Player extends Player],
  PlayerRanking: [class PlayerRanking extends PlayerRanking],
  Client: [class Client extends Client],
  API: [class API extends API],
  default: {
    client: [class Client extends Client],
    api: [class API extends API]
  }
}
```

showing that `require` returned an object, not a class.

**Short term solution**

Either

```
const BrawlStarsAPI = require("brawlstars-api-nodejs").API; // or
const BrawlStarsAPI = require("brawlstars-api-nodejs").default.api;
```

correctly retrieves the class API for use by adding object property names to retrieve it. While this seems to work on package files *installed on your machine* it is doubtful that it is intended as a final configuration.

**Why**

The package installed does not match the documentation on the [Github master branch](https://github.com/awekrx/BrawlStarsAPI/tree/master) (the link provided on NPM) - perhaps it is being updated to use `import` instead of `require`.

**Reporting**

The master `package.json` file includes the following entry if you choose to follow up on it:

```
"bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/awekrx/BrawlStarsAPI/issues"
},
```

**Methodology**

1. It doesn't work according to documentation example
2. The call to require didn't error, so what did it return instead of  a class object?

   1. console log the return value to inspect it.
3. oh, it's an object with `API` and `default.api` properties.

   1. Test if one or both of these properties is the API that allows you to retrieve a client.
   2. Yes they do ( in fact`.API` and `.default.api` are strictly equal)

**Question**

Given that `require` of a JavaScript module in node returns its default export, the object returned by `require` could be a module export. However inspection of `package.json` on GitHub didn't show any `.mjs` files or reveal other signs of modular script usage (to me).

**Conclusion**

The docs don't align with package files. Perhaps the author is updating the master branch at this time and has yet to update the docs. I simply don't know, but did see the issues link in the package file whilst looking at it.

```
const BrawlStarsAPI = require("brawlstars-api-nodejs").API;
```

may be a long term solution if the package code is working correctly and the only issue is that the docs have yet to be updated.

Comment: how did you do this? asking so i can do it myself the next time.

Comment: I've added some methodology notes and thought processes. Hope it helps and happy coding!